# What is the best way to know the User who is log?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Hello i have the next design problem:

Before accessing to my Controller i have a filter to check the authentication and the authorization so in order to do so i have to know the user. Until there everything is perfect, but the problem starts when i want to know the user who is log so i can do more things. Any ideas?

```cs
[AdministratorAuth("DogController")] 
public class DogController : ControllerBase
{    
   [HttpGet]
   public IAction GetDogsOfUser()
   {
       return Ok(dogLogic.GetDogsOfUser());
   }
}
```

```cs
public class LoginAuth : Attribute, IActionFilter
    {
        public static Guid Token { get; private set; }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {

        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            string headerToken = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

            if (headerToken is null) 
            {
                context.Result = new ContentResult()
                {
                    Content = "Token is required",
                };
            } else 
            {
                try 
                {
                    Guid token = Guid.Parse(headerToken);
                    VerifyToken(token, context);
                    Token = token;
                } catch (FormatException) 
                {
                    context.Result = new ContentResult()
                    {
                        Content = "Invalid Token format",
                    };
                }
            }
        }

        private void VerifyToken(Guid token, ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            using (var sessions = GetSessionLogic(context)) 
            {
                if (!sessions.IsValidToken(token)) 
                {
                    context.Result = new ContentResult()
                    {
                        Content = "Invalid Token",
                    };
                }
            }
        }

        private ISessionLogic GetSessionLogic(ActionExecutingContext context) 
        {
            var typeOfSessionsLogic = typeof(ISessionLogic);
            return context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeOfSessionsLogic) as ISessionLogic;
        }
    }
```

```cs
public class AdministratorAuth : LoginAuth
    {
        private readonly string permission;

        public AdministratorAuth(string permission)
        {
            this.permission = permission;
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {

        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
            string headerToken = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            Guid token = Guid.Parse(headerToken);

            using (var sessions = GetSessionLogic(context)) 
            {
                if (!sessions.HasLevel(token, permission)) 
                {
                    context.Result = new ContentResult()
                    {
                        Content = "The user hasn't the permission to access " + permission,
                    };   
                }
            }
        }

        private ISessionLogic GetSessionLogic(ActionExecutingContext context) 
        {
            var typeOfSessionsLogic = typeof(ISessionLogic);
            return context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeOfSessionsLogic) as ISessionLogic;
        }
    }
```

So let's imagine that i have this, if i want to know the dogs of the user who is log, how can i do?

Comment: It depends on the implementation of `AdministratorAuthAttribute`. That doesn't look like a standard out-of-the-box MVC attribute.

Comment: I edit the question so you can see my filter class AdministratorAuth and my LoginAuth

Comment: Why are you doing all this extra work when Identity does it all for you?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: from tags I can see, that you use `EF Core` with classic `ASP.Net MVC`. Are you sure that you not on `ASP.Net Core MVC`?

Comment: I'm using yes EF Core and Asp.Net Core

Comment: what you have writen above is already implemented in [ASP.Net Core Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2), have a look at [Claims-based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-2.2) or [Policy-based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2) authorization.

Comment: It doesn’t matter how is implemented my filters, i just want to know how to catch the user log

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel. All this already exists. Read the docs.

Answer (score -4):

You can simply use ***Nlog*** or ***log4net*** function,

or

create a model which contains

```
Logged = DateTime.Now,
LoginHost = Request.Host.ToString(),
LoginIP = Request.HttpContext.Connection.LocalIpAddress.ToString(),
SessionId = Request.HttpContext.Session.Id
```

Comment: Could you be more specific in showing and helping me on how to implement a correct solution for this example? I want to know the user log in the class DogLogic because i have the logic there

Comment: @ Daniel Acevedo, it depend on  about your authentication, for example if you use asp.net identity you can access to claims value and have many info about user log: HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims, it depend on your authentication

Comment: I edit the questions so you can see. I understand what you are saying but i don't think is entirely correct doing that what you are saying in DogController